# NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData returns weird array instead of dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to parse data from an HTTP response like this:

```
let dataDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSMutableDictionary
```

As a result I get this really weird array:

```
(lldb) po dataDictionary
▿ 3 elements
▿ [0] : 2 elements
  - .0 : message
  - .1 : http://abc.abc
▿ [1] : 2 elements
  - .0 : xyz
  - .1 : 1234
▿ [2] : 2 elements
  - .0 : status
  - .1 : ok
```

This was the data I've received (formatted it nicely, no line breaks):

```
{
 "message": "http://abc.abc",
 "xyz": "1234",
 "status": "ok"
}
```

Is this an encoding issue? What is happening here?

Comment: Do not use `NSMutable(Array|Dictionary)` in Swift unless you have absolutely no choice. Use Swift native collection types (in this particular case `[String:String]`), then you get mutability for free and you can omit the `MutableContainers` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an array, it's your NSMutableDictionary.

It looks like that when printed in the debugger: there's 3 entries, each one has a key and a value.

Do <kbd>ALT+CLICK</kbd> on `dataDictionary` and read the Xcode tip, you'll see the type.

Comment: Thanks, the json parsing worked, it was the debugger output that confused me.